# Dissolving Image Particles js

Tags: javascript, image, animation, particles

I am trying to create an animation something like that:
http://neverbland.com/

But instead of that text, I need to use the logo (image), I can't figure out how can I create that explosion from the middle of the image.

Did anyone do that before? 
Thanks!

html:

```
<div class="explosion_container">
<canvas widht="100%" height="500px" class="explosion"></canvas>

<div class="waio_logo_container">
    <svg id="waio_logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 314.31 89.55"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#2e2f2f;}.cls-2{fill:#fdb515;}.cls-3{fill:#f68720;}.cls-4{fill:#f16025;}.cls-5{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Asset 2ldpi</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M105.36,81.5a3.92,3.92,0,0,1,3.84-4.12,3.27,3.27,0,0,1,3,1.8V71.64h1.32V85.49h-1.32l0-1.71a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-3.07,1.86A3.93,3.93,0,0,1,105.36,81.5Zm6.94,0a2.75,2.75,0,0,0-2.82-2.93,3,3,0,0,0,0,5.91A2.77,2.77,0,0,0,112.3,81.5Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M116.17,74.31a1,1,0,0,1,1.92,0,1,1,0,0,1-1.92,0Zm.29,3.24h1.34v7.94h-1.34Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M121.2,78.68h-1.28V77.55h1.28V74.33c0-1.78.9-2.55,2.19-2.55a2.31,2.31,0,0,1,2,.84l-.86.84a1.13,1.13,0,0,0-1-.48c-.58,0-1,.31-1,1.34v3.22h3.57v-3.6c0-1.78.9-2.55,2.21-2.55a2.26,2.26,0,0,1,2,1l-.88.79a1.13,1.13,0,0,0-1-.56c-.58,0-1,.33-1,1.34v3.6h2.13v1.13h-2.13v6.81h-1.34V78.68h-3.57v6.81H121.2Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M135.16,84.51a3.24,3.24,0,0,0,2.51-1.06l.82.81a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-3.34,1.38,4.13,4.13,0,1,1-.19-8.26c2.55,0,4.08,2,4,4.58H132.2A2.74,2.74,0,0,0,135.16,84.51Zm2.45-3.57A2.48,2.48,0,0,0,135,78.51a2.66,2.66,0,0,0-2.74,2.44Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M141.26,77.55h1.34l0,1.55a2.46,2.46,0,0,1,2.32-1.71,2.31,2.31,0,0,1,1.38.38l-.52,1.17a1.85,1.85,0,0,0-1.09-.31c-1.13,0-2.05.81-2.05,2.67v4.18h-1.34Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M151.71,84.51a3.24,3.24,0,0,0,2.51-1.06l.82.81a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-3.34,1.38,4.13,4.13,0,1,1-.19-8.26c2.55,0,4.08,2,4,4.58h-6.75A2.74,2.74,0,0,0,151.71,84.51Zm2.45-3.57a2.48,2.48,0,0,0-2.65-2.44,2.66,2.66,0,0,0-2.74,2.44Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M157.81,77.55h1.34l0,1.63a3,3,0,0,1,2.86-1.8c1.76,0,3,1.21,3,3.28v4.83H163.6V80.81c0-1.4-.65-2.21-2-2.21a2.33,2.33,0,0,0-2.47,2.51v4.37h-1.34Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M168.07,83.09V78.68h-1.23V77.55h1.23V73.41h1.32v4.14h2.22v1.13h-2.22v4.43c0,1.06.36,1.38.94,1.38A1.45,1.45,0,0,0,171.4,84l.73.84a2.58,2.58,0,0,1-1.94.79C169,85.66,168.07,85,168.07,83.09Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M179.19,83.78l0,1.71h-1.32V71.64h1.32v7.54a3.31,3.31,0,0,1,3-1.8,4.14,4.14,0,0,1,0,8.26A3.34,3.34,0,0,1,179.19,83.78Zm5.54-2.28A2.7,2.7,0,0,0,182,78.57a3,3,0,1,0,2.74,2.93Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M190.7,84.82l-3.38-7.27h1.48L191,82.48a8.14,8.14,0,0,1,.36,1.34,6.45,6.45,0,0,1,.36-1.34l2.07-4.93h1.38l-5.18,12h-1.38Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M200.46,81.5a3.92,3.92,0,0,1,3.84-4.12,3.27,3.27,0,0,1,3,1.8V71.64h1.32V85.49h-1.32l0-1.71a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-3.07,1.86A3.93,3.93,0,0,1,200.46,81.5Zm6.94,0a2.75,2.75,0,0,0-2.82-2.93,3,3,0,0,0,0,5.91A2.77,2.77,0,0,0,207.4,81.5Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M215.32,84.51a3.24,3.24,0,0,0,2.51-1.06l.82.81a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-3.34,1.38,4.13,4.13,0,1,1-.19-8.26c2.55,0,4.08,2,4,4.58h-6.75A2.74,2.74,0,0,0,215.32,84.51Zm2.45-3.57a2.48,2.48,0,0,0-2.65-2.44,2.66,2.66,0,0,0-2.74,2.44Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M221.84,78.68h-1.28V77.55h1.28v-3.6c0-1.78.9-2.55,2.21-2.55a2.26,2.26,0,0,1,2,1l-.88.79a1.13,1.13,0,0,0-1-.56c-.58,0-1,.33-1,1.34v3.6h2.13v1.13h-2.13v6.81h-1.34Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M232.16,80.64c0-1.53-.69-2.13-1.86-2.13A2.71,2.71,0,0,0,228,79.66l-.82-.75a3.77,3.77,0,0,1,3.24-1.53,2.92,2.92,0,0,1,3.11,3.24v4.87h-1.34l.06-1.19a3,3,0,0,1-2.63,1.34c-1.69,0-2.91-.77-2.91-2.42s1.34-2.4,3-2.4h2.47Zm-2.38,1.21c-1,0-1.8.36-1.8,1.32s.67,1.38,1.92,1.38,2.26-.67,2.26-1.71v-1Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M236.09,82.42V77.55h1.34v4.74c0,1.38.65,2.15,2,2.15a2.33,2.33,0,0,0,2.47-2.51V77.55h1.34v7.94h-1.34l0-1.61a3,3,0,0,1-2.84,1.78A2.91,2.91,0,0,1,236.09,82.42Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M246.14,71.64h1.34V85.49h-1.34Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M250.88,83.09V78.68h-1.23V77.55h1.23V73.41h1.32v4.14h2.22v1.13H252.2v4.43c0,1.06.36,1.38.94,1.38a1.45,1.45,0,0,0,1.07-.46l.73.84a2.58,2.58,0,0,1-1.94.79C251.8,85.66,250.88,85,250.88,83.09Z"/><rect class="cls-2" x="23.51" y="38.29" width="39.16" height="10.79" transform="translate(-18.27 43.26) rotate(-45)"/><polygon class="cls-3" points="25.43 53.71 30.12 26.02 37.75 33.66 33.06 61.35 25.43 53.71"/><polygon class="cls-3" points="53.12 26.02 60.75 33.66 56.06 61.35 48.43 53.71 53.12 26.02"/><path class="cls-1" d="M191.37,36.53l3.56-10,3.54,10c.43,1.38.79,2.48,1.12,3.4l9.21,25.65h10.73L196.47,1.46h-3.07l-11.07,30.7-.09.3-11.9,33.06h10.73l9.21-25.65C190.6,39,191,37.86,191.37,36.53Z"/><rect class="cls-1" x="227.73" y="2.04" width="11.26" height="63.48"/><path class="cls-1" d="M283,1.2c-17.27,0-31.31,14.43-31.31,32.16s14,32.16,31.31,32.16,31.31-14.43,31.31-32.16S300.27,1.2,283,1.2Zm0,53.61c-11.54,0-20.93-9.62-20.93-21.45S271.46,11.91,283,11.91s20.93,9.62,20.93,21.45S294.54,54.81,283,54.81Z"/><path class="cls-4" d="M37.75,33.66,30.12,26,8.24,47.91a32.33,32.33,0,0,0,3,12.25Z"/><path class="cls-4" d="M48.43,53.71l7.63,7.63L79.68,37.76c-.19-4.38-1.79-8-3.53-11.73Z"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="165.19 2.05 151.6 41.02 151.27 40.38 134.9 2.04 131.22 2.04 115.56 40.99 115.47 41.18 101.69 2.05 89.64 2.05 112.87 65.52 113.97 65.52 115.36 65.52 133.15 23.93 150.7 65.52 152.17 65.52 153.19 65.52 153.22 65.52 176.07 2.05 165.19 2.05"/><path class="cls-1" d="M43.12,0C19.34,0,0,19.6,0,43.68S19.34,87.37,43.12,87.37A42.55,42.55,0,0,0,73.6,74.58,43.69,43.69,0,0,0,86.23,43.68C86.23,19.6,66.89,0,43.12,0Zm0,78.58a34.9,34.9,0,0,1,0-69.8,34.9,34.9,0,0,1,0,69.8Z"/><rect class="cls-5" x="292.88" y="72.9" width="9.92" height="12.59"/><rect class="cls-1" x="263.13" y="72.9" width="9.92" height="12.59"/><rect class="cls-4" x="273.05" y="72.9" width="9.92" height="12.59"/><rect class="cls-3" x="282.97" y="72.9" width="9.92" height="12.59"/><rect class="cls-2" x="292.88" y="72.9" width="9.92" height="12.59"/></g></g></svg>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var tap = ('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
var loadAnimation = function(){
    document.body.classList.add('ready');
    var canvas = document.querySelector('.explosion');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var numberOfParticules = 300;
    var x = 0;
    var distance = window.innerWidth;
    var y = 0;
    var animations = [];
    var colors = ['#f16026', '#fdb414', '#f16026', '#000000'];

    var getFontSize = function() {
        return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
    }
    var setCanvasSize = function(){
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
    var createCircle = function(x,y){
        var p = {};
        p.x = x;
        p.y = y;
        p.color = '#fff';
        p.radius = 0;
        p.alpha = 1;
        p.lineWidth = 3;
        p.draw = function(){
            ctx.globalAlpha = p.alpha;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2* Math.PI, true);
            ctx.lineWidth = p.lineWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = p.color;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        }
        return p;
    }
   var createParticule = function(x,y) {
    var p = {};
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    p.color = colors[anime.random(0, colors.length - 1)];
    p.radius = anime.random(getFontSize(), getFontSize() * 0.51);
    p.draw = function() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      ctx.fillStyle = p.color;
      ctx.fill();
    }
    return p;
  }
    var createParticles = function(x,y) {
    var particles = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParticules; i++) {
          var p = createParticule(x, y);
          particles.push(p);
        }
        return particles;
    }
    var animateParticles = function(x,y){
        setCanvasSize();
        var particles = createParticles(x,y);
        var circle = createCircle(x,y);
        var particlesAnimation = anime({
            targets: particles,
            x: function(p) {return p.x + anime.random(-distance, distance);},
            y:function(p) {return p.y + anime.random(-250, 250);},
            radius:0,
            duration: function(){
                return anime.random(2200,2800);
            },
            easing: 'easeOutExpo'
        });
        var circleAnimation = anime({
            targets: circle,
            radius:function(){ return anime.random(getFontSize() * 8.75, getFontSize() * 11.25); },
            alpha:{
                value:0,
                easing: 'linear',
                duration: function(){
                    return anime.random(400,600);
                },
            duration:function(){
                return anime.random(2200, 2800);
            },
            easing: 'easeOutExpo'

            }
        });
        animations.push(particlesAnimation, circleAnimation);
    }
    var mainLoop = anime({
    duration: Infinity,
    update: function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      animations.forEach(function(anim) {
        anim.animatables.forEach(function(animatable) {
          animatable.target.draw();
        });
      });
    }
  });
  var updateCoords = function(){
    x = window.innerWidth / 2;
    y = 900 / 2;
  }
    var setDashoffset = function(el) {
        var l = el.getTotalLength();
        el.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', l);
        return [l,0];
    }
    var start_circle = anime({
        targets: '#waio_logo',
        transform: ['scale(1)', 'scale(0)'],
        delay: function(el,i){
            return 500 + (i*100)
        },
        duration: 900,
        complete: function(){
            updateCoords(),
            animateParticles(x,y)
        }
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadAnimation, false);
```

DEMO:
http://epicode.ro/js_animation.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code that we can help you with.

Comment: I have just updated my post. I uploaded all my code. My problem is that I can't figure out how to dissole the image like in the above example. Now I have a scale effect.

Comment: so what's your question? If anyone done this before is probably not the only thing you want to know

Comment: I need some help to achive to effect. Maybe someone did something like that before to give me a point to start, usually I come here when I am totally out of ideas.